# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when trying to access HTML string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to build a Tax/MOT checker where a user would enter a registration plate into my application, it sends the number plate into a car checker website (which scraps data from DVLA) and retrieves TAX and MOT information which is then sent back to the application once car details are viewed, I've researched a lot on the way as I just started learning more about android studio and complex java code in general. Anyway, the issue I seem to be having relates to when my html link is passed through HttpURLConnection where it instantly crashes the application. I looked in the logcat and it came up with **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** as the main culprit.

I've seen other threads about this where an Async subclass can be used but that has since been deprecated in favour of java.util.concurrent which I have limited knowledge on.

Here is the code for my CarSearch (Tax/MOT check) function when the insert vehicle button is clicked, after the '2' toast I seem to run into the error:

```
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String vehiclenameTXT = name.getText().toString();
            String numberplateTXT = plate.getText().toString();
            String mileageTXT = mileage.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(CarSearch.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Boolean checkinsertdata = DB.insertvehicledata(vehiclenameTXT, numberplateTXT, mileageTXT);
            if(checkinsertdata==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(CarSearch.this, "New Vehicle Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(CarSearch.this, "Cannot add the same vehicle details twice!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try {

                Toast.makeText(CarSearch.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String addr = "https://cartaxcheck.co.uk/free-car-check/?vrm=LN11VUM";
                URL url = new URL(addr);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    content.setText(inputLine);
                in.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(CarSearch.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Here is the error I get thrown in the logcat:

```
2021-10-16 21:46:30.798 26220-26220/com.example.projectsupercars E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.projectsupercars, PID: 26220
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.example.projectsupercars.CarSearch$1.onClick(CarSearch.java:73)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I know what needs to be done but I have trouble seeing how to do it. How can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: There are **90 answers** on the duplicate question. Personally, I would be using [OkHttp and its built-in asynchronous HTTP request capability](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java).

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I might go on that actually

Comment: It worked! This way is much easier than what I was trying before, thank you!